# Validate with Kendo

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

How do I validate using Kendo,

I added a normal textbox

```
@Html.Kendo().HtmlHelper.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.Kendo().HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

and I added the following to the model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name.")]
```

The validation is not shown on form submission, any idea on how to get the message to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your `kendoValidator()` call in your JavaScript? You have to tell Kendo what container you want validated and then you have to call the `validate()` method of the validator object.

Here is a [Validator Demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/validator/index.html)